# My FBX import doesn't have any animation and looks very deformed. Help!

Tags: animation, export, bones, import, .fbx

I'm new to blender, and I've been working on this game that has a reload animation for the First Person. When I look at the .blend file, the animation is there and the 3D looks fine. However, when I export it as FBX file and then Import it back to blender, the animation is gone and the meshes look all squashed up. I've been looking everywhere to try to fix it, but I've got no such luck.
This is what it looks like on the .blend file:
[image: .blend file]

This is what is looks like when I import it FBX file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you apply all the modifiers? Its usually the root of my problems when I'm exporting things to other formats.

Comment: Yes, All the modifiers are there, I notice the transformation on the import is completely different to the .blend file. I've tried doing CTRL+A  and set  the scale but its still wont work...

Comment: Could you provide your blender file so I could take a look?

Comment: Wait! I fixed the issue! Thank you very much though!

Comment: How did you fixed it, Gonzalo Martinez?